# Adding REST Web Service annotation in API class

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, api-design

I am using Spring Boot (1.5.3) to create a Spring REST Web Service. I have added `spring-boot-starter-web` as the only dependency (as per spring guide). Next I have created `UserManagementService` interface for my service class.

```
@RequestMapping("/usermanagement/v1")
public interface UserManagementService {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public UserTo getUserById(@PathVariable("id") long id);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<UserTo> getAllUsers();
}
```

And its implementation `UserManagementServiceImpl`

```
@RestController
public class UserManagementServiceImpl implements UserManagementService {

    private Map<Integer, UserTo> users;

    public UserManagementServiceImpl() {
        users = new HashMap<>();
        users.put(1, new UserTo(1, "Smantha Barnes"));
        users.put(2, new UserTo(2, "Adam Bukowski"));
        users.put(3, new UserTo(3, "Meera Nair"));
    }

    public UserTo getUserById(long id) {
        return users.get(id);
    }

    public List<UserTo> getAllUsers() {
        List<UserTo> usersList = new ArrayList<UserTo>(users.values());
        return usersList;
    }

}
```

I wanted to created a REST Web Service using Spring Boot with minimum configuration and thought this would work. But on accessing my the Web Service I am getting No Response. What I am missing?

Also, I have seen many projects where annotations are added to the interface rather than the implementation class. Which I think is better than annotating classes. It should work here, right?

Comment: You will have to check, but I'm not sure that annotations are properly handled by interfaces, as it is not the exact class that is instantiated. And on a more opinion-based thought, you should call your services for users the same way: what i mean is `@RequestMapping(value = "/users/{id}/", method=RequestMethod.GET)` and `@RequestMapping(value = "/users/", method=RequestMethod.GET)` as you want all users or one user from the list of users. But the second part of the comment is up to you.

Comment: @DamCx I tried different scenarios and "@PathVariable" don't seem to work in method declaration in the interface. It works in the implementation class only. The rest of the annotations in the code are working fine in the interface.

Answer (score 0):

As [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46419390/adding-rest-web-service-annotation-in-api-class/46419527#comment79796175_46419390), not all annotations are supported on interfaces. The `@PathVariable` annotation for example won't work, so you'll have to put that on the implementation itself:

```
public UserTo getUserById(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
    return users.get(id);
}
```

Additionally to that, you have a `Map<Integer, UserTo>`, but you're retrieving the users using a `@PathVariable` of type `long`. This won't work either, so either change the key of `users` to `Long` or the `id` parameter to `int`:

```
public UserTo getUserById(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
    return users.get(id);
}
```

The reason for this is that `1L` (`long`) is not the same as `1` (`int`). So retrieving a map entry wouldn't return any result for a `long` value.